# What rating can I add to a commercial certificate with the least time/effort?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification

I have an FAA commercial certificate with ASEL, AMEL, ASES, Glider and Instrument ratings (alongside specific type ratings). What additional certificate or rating will require the shortest amount of training to add?

It could be anything from sport pilot through ATP certificate, for any class: weight shift, multi engine seaplane, gyro-copter etc.

Comment: now reads "quickest (in terms of prerequisites and\or flight hours)"

Comment: Just curious, why are you asking? Why the desire to add something to your license quickly?

Comment: Does a Part 107 certificate count? You could get it in a day just by doing the knowledge test but it's a separate certificate, not an add-on to an existing one, so it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: After thinking some more I've voted to close this as unclear because I'm not sure what you consider a valid answer. E.g. you could get Part 107 or Ground Instructor with only written tests, but is that what you mean? Or are you asking about something that gives you more flight privileges? And what about your hours and experience? Is there an 'easy' type rating in an aircraft that you have prior experience in? Do you have enough hours for ATP already? Maybe private balloon (10hrs training) is closest to what you're asking, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1):

[Jack Brown's Seaplane Base](http://brownsseaplane.com) offers single engine seaplane ratings at private and commercial level.  It takes 2 full days and costs between 1400 USD and 2300 USD depending on your choice of training aircraft.

From their website:

> **SES Rating**
>
> We offer three options of planes for your SES training at the private
>   or commercial level, both of which include: 1.5 hours of ground
>   instruction, 5 hours of dual instruction, the check ride and the
>   examiner’s fee.
>
> Training in the Piper J3-Cub on floats,  1,400.00.
>
> Training in the Maule M-7 on floats,     2,300.00.
>
> Training in the Super Cub on floats,     1,850.00.
>
> If additional flight instruction hours are required they are billable
>   at the hourly rate of the aircraft (listed below).

They are located in Winter Haven, FL.